# Iterate through all possibilities in Julia

Tags: julia

If I want to do something on each pair of letters, it could look like this in Julia:

```
for l1 in 'a':'z'
    for l2 in 'a':'z'
        w = l1*l2
        # ... do something with w ...
    end
end
```

I want to generalise this to words of any length, given a value `n` specifying the number of letters desired. How do I best do this in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
for ls in Iterators.product(fill('a':'z', n)...))
    w = join(ls)
    # ... do something with w ...
end
```

In particular if you wanted to collect them in an array you could write:

```
join.(Iterators.product(fill('a':'z', n)...))
```

or flatten it to a vector

```
vec(join.(Iterators.product(fill('a':'z', n)...)))
```

Note, however, that in most cases this will not be needed and for larger `n` it is better not to materialize the output but just iterate over it as suggested above.